Get current audio source on Windows. Python
I'm looking for a way to get current audio source.
On Windows when you stop the audio there is a tab on the top with audio name. I'm trying to get this information but nowhere in the Internet found an answer.
Maybe someone has an idea
I've tried PyAudio and WinSound libraries but got nothing. They can only play sound.
Also there is a way to get audio from microphone but I don't want to keep microphone all the time

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
